# Definition of connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

The definition of a connected graph states that:
A graph $G$ is called connected provided for each pair $a,b$ with $a\neq b$ of vertices $\exists$ a walk joining a and b.(equivalently a chain joining $a$ and $b$)...

What does the definition mean by *(equivalently a chain joining $a$ and $b$)* .Please help...

Comment: You need to give the definition of a walk and a chain for this question to be answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chain is simply a sequence of edges, forming a path.

A path is a walk without repeated vertices.

If there is a walk between two vertices a and b, there is also a path connecting them.

Comment: can you please elaborate this line:If there is a walk between two vertices a and b, there is also a path connecting them.  what I can't understand is if I have a walk b/w a and b , not necessarily consisting of distinct vertices..then how do I obtain a path from it ....

Comment: An example : Let a-c-d-e-d-c-b be a walk from a to b. Then, you can delete the part d-e-d-c and get the path a-c-b.

Comment: In general, a walk c-x-c-d (x an arbitary walk) can be replaced by c-d. You can continue until there are no more repeated vertices.

Comment: I think you need to modify definition of chain...it should also not have repeated edges...

Comment: repeated edges imply repeated vertices.

Comment: then what will be the difference between path and chain...as you stated

Comment: Where did I claim that there is a difference ?

Comment: I mean your first statement :A chain is simply a sequence of edges, forming a path.Is there really some difference between them..

Comment: No, a chain is essentially the same as a path. The difference, if there is any, is only a formal one. In the wikipedia glossary, it is stated that a chain is another word for a path.

Comment: Perhaps, the word path refers to the whole sequence, and the word chain refers to the edges.

Answer (score -1):

An undirected graph is connected when there is a path between every pair of vertices. In a connected graph, there are no unreachable vertices. A graph that is not connected is disconnected. An undirected graph G is said to be disconnected if there exist two nodes in G such that no path in G has those nodes as endpoints.
A graph with just one vertex is connected. An edgeless graph with two or more vertices is disconnected